# How to find the first visible Label in an autoscroll Panel during scroll

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

Hello I have a question. 
I have a `Panel` which contains for example 1000 `Label` controls that the height of each label is variable in a Windows Forms Application and I am going to find the position of the first label which is seen in the panel when scrolling the panel vertically.

Here is an screenshot of my `Panel` and `Label` controls:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the top `Label` control in the container `Panel` regardless of their sizes and distances this way:

```
private void container_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    var labels = container.Controls.OfType<Label>().OrderBy(x => x.Top);
    var top = labels.Where(l => container.ClientRectangle.IntersectsWith(l.Bounds))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
    if (top != null)
    {
        this.Text = top.Name;
        top.BackColor = Color.Gold;
        labels.Except(new[] { top }).ToList().ForEach(x => x.BackColor = Color.Silver);
    }
}
```

In above code, I first performed an order-by on labels based on their `Top`, then I got the first label which its bound intersects with the container panel.

To find position of top item, after you find it, use `top.Location`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the `Controls` collection until you find a `Label`:

```
Label getTopLabel(Panel container)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 60; y+= 10)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)container.GetChildAtPoint(new Point(20, y));
        if (lbl != null) return lbl;
    }
    return null;
}
```

My example assumes that no gap between two `Labels` is greater than `60` pixels and all `Labels` can be found at `X=20` and are at least `10 pixels` tall.. Modify to suit your numbers!

You can call the function whenever you need to..:

```
private void panel1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    Control ctl = getTopLabel(panel1);
    if (ctl != null) Text = ctl.Name;
}
```

Comment: Ohh! TaW this code is OK only for scrolling but when I click up or Down it doesn't work

Comment: What is 'Up' and 'Down' ? Also: You can easily tranform it into a function and call it whenever you want..

Comment: Thanks for your solution rights The right was with you(Your Solution Was OK )